# Is System.Security.CodeAccessPermission obsolete in .NET Core 3.1 / .NET 5.0?

Tags: c#, .net, security

I know that [CAS is obsolete in .NET Core 3.1 / .NET 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/code-access-security-basics).

Is `System.Security.CodeAccessPermission` also obsolete? I was unable to find any reliable information about it on Internet. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.codeaccesspermission?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) don't say anything about it, and just a few methods - like the `Deny()` method - are [marked as obsolete on the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.codeaccesspermission.deny?view=netcore-3.1#System_Security_CodeAccessPermission_Deny).

Assuming that they are all obsolete - and that's why I couldn't find any current articles or books about it, - **what should I use instead?** Can you please point me to some docs or books that discuss the current state of code access security on .NET Framework 4.8 / Core 3.1 / 5.0? I couldn't find any!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what part of code access security you're looking for? Perhaps alternatives can be suggested.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnetcore

Comment: @V0ldek, fixed!

Comment: @CodeCaster, to be honest, I'm not sure how to answer your question. I'm thinking about implementing code security in my application using the PermissionSetAttribute, but I'm not sure if this is part of CAS or not. I couldn't find any documentation clarifying what is considered part of "CAS" in .NET and what isn't. What I'm trying to achieve is to prevent other assemblies from calling methods on my own assembly (dll) and to check some user permissions throughout the API. Not sure how yet. I'm still researching and trying to find a solution for this.

Comment: @jdweng, interesting, thanks! Unfortunately, not a single mention to "code access" or "permission" on this article.

Comment: "Documentation" is never as fresh as the code https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d252f297d38c897ca889cf6e2f01d9766d758c87/src/libraries/System.Security.Permissions/src/System/Security/CodeAccessPermission.cs So it is obsolete in .NET 5 and above. To migrate away, follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/code-access-security-policy-compatibility-and-migration#migration-replacement-for-obsolete-calls

Comment: @LexLi, thank you for your idea. It should probably be an answer, as I probably won't get any good alternatives for my app. Would you like to promote it so I can mark it as the answer?
Also, good catch! If you look at the history, this class was marked as obsolete mere 22 days ago!
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/d252f297d38c897ca889cf6e2f01d9766d758c87/src/libraries/System.Security.Permissions/src/System/Security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from the comment.

There can be significant delay between code change and documentation update. So we should focus on the code first, which is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d252f297d38c897ca889cf6e2f01d9766d758c87/src/libraries/System.Security.Permissions/src/System/Security/CodeAccessPermission.cs). From there we can see this type only becomes obsolete in .NET 5.

To migrate away from obsolete types, you can follow [the guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/code-access-security-policy-compatibility-and-migration#migration-replacement-for-obsolete-calls).